# Spring non-transactional nested method inside @Transactional is the same as @Transactional propagation = support

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-transactions

1) Are there any difference

- if I call a *non-transactional* method from inside `@Transactional` method
- call a @`Transactional` method with propagation level [`SUPPORTS`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.2.x-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/TransactionDefinition.html#PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS) from the same @Transactional method?

2) Are there any difference if answer for the first question if it's the *same bean* or different?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> i) Are there any difference,
>
> 1) if I call a non-transactional method from inside @transactional AND

If you call a method within a transaction, without any settings, the transaction will span to the calling method.

> 2) call call a @transactional with propagation level = support from the same @transactional method?

`Propagation.SUPPORTS` annotated method will be executed in the current transaction, just like if you call a non-transactional method.

The only different between setting `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)` and not setting `@Transactional` is noted in [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#SUPPORTS):

> Note: For transaction managers with transaction synchronization, PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS is slightly different from no transaction at all, as it defines a transaction scope that synchronization will apply for. As a consequence, the same resources (JDBC Connection, Hibernate Session, etc) will be shared for the entire specified scope. Note that this depends on the actual synchronization configuration of the transaction manager.
>
> ii) Are there any difference if answer for the question i) if it's the same bean or different?

Spring `@Transactional` annotation default using AOP proxy.

When you calling `methodB` from `methodA` within the same class, the AOP proxy will not be activated for the `methodB` (i.e `@Transactional` annotation in `methodB` is completely ignored).

When you calling from different class, then the behavior is same as `i)`

Comment: ---it defines a transaction scope that synchronization will apply for. As a consequence, the same resources (JDBC Connection, Hibernate Session, etc) will be shared for the entire specified scope---

Comment: Do you mean, in non-transactional nested method it will no these objects: JDBC Connection, Hibernate Session, etc be accessible?